# mysqldump only view definitions, triggers, routines and events

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to export these database objects into a file. It should be in such a way that running that file (later) is able to recreate the same views, triggers, functions, stored procedures and events in the original, or a different database.

In other words, I do not want table definitions and their associated indexes and constraints.

I had expected straightforward options for this to be available on `mysqldump`, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

This almost does it for me:

```
mysqldump -u root -p source_database --no-data --no-create-db --no-create-info 
--routines --triggers --skip-opt --set-gtid-purged=OFF > db_objects.sql
```

But conspicuously missing are `events` and `views`. Also, I need to have each object DROPPED or REPLACED as the case may be, since it may already exist.

I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction. Perhaps I need to leverage a script to achieve this?

**EDIT**: Why do I need this?

I would like to be able to run a script that recreates all these objects in one go. This could be part of maintenance of a production server, using updated counterparts from a dev server.

Now, certain tables on the prod server might also need to be updated (ALTERED), but these are more sensitive and require a lot more thought. It is my understanding that you may drop and recreate views, events, triggers and routines 24 times a day (now I'm exaggerating!) with little concern for data conflicts.

Comment: There is probably a workaround, but an explanation of why you want to exclude tables but include views, and how you will use this file could be important.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I have tried it don't show me any tables in .sql file

```
mysqldump -u root -p blog2 --no-data --no-create-db --no-create-info --routines --triggers --skip-opt --lock-tables --set-gtid-purged=OFF > blogs2.sql
```

Comment: Does it dump events and views?

Comment: I don't have table which contains events and views. You can try it.. [--locktables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables) only lock tables according to MySQL guide

Comment: So like I already said in the question, "But conspicuously missing are events and views."  That means they are not dropped. My DB does have events and views.

Comment: do you only want table on back up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "--events"

Also, for views, you might need a newer version of MySQL.

--add-drop-table (put it after --skip-opt) might work for older versions.

From the manual:

--compact

```
       Produce more compact output. This option enables the --skip-add-drop-table, --skip-add-locks, --skip-comments,
       --skip-disable-keys, and --skip-set-charset options.

           Note
           Prior to MySQL 5.1.21, this option did not create valid SQL if the database dump contained views. The recreation of
           views requires the creation and removal of temporary tables and this option suppressed the removal of those temporary
           tables. As a workaround, use --compact with the --add-drop-table option and then manually adjust the dump file.
```

Answer (score -1):

MYSQL : Dump database with procedures, functions, views & triggers.

Export database with all procedures, functions, views & triggers along with the table structures and their data.

`mysqldump <other mysqldump options> --routines export.sql`

Comment: `--routines` will only gets Stored procedures and Functions. 
Note: mysqldump will not provide a way to dump the views.